# Node Express: Requests are taking Top-level domain as the subdomain ??

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, subdomain

I am working on a express project where subdomains are used.

Now the problem i am facing is that my domain name is ("companyName.co.in") and my node JS code is considering companyName as the subdomain.

Here is my code:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
//app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('../app'));
app.use(express.static('static/'));

app.use('/api/user',require('./controllers/user.controller'));


var server = app.listen(3000,function(){    
    console.log('Server listening at 3000');
});
```

**user.controller.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/details", getUserDetails);

function getUserDetails(req, res) {
    var subdomain = (req.subdomains.length > 0) ? req.subdomains[0] : '';
    console.log(subdomain)
}

module.exports = router;
```

So when i call the api/user/details i find that it gives the companyName as the subdomain.

like:   requesting from "companyName.co.in"
subdomain should be null but it gives me subdomain as companyName.

Can you please help how can i let the node server know that "companyName.co.in" this is the host and also allow "*.companyName.co.in" where the subdomain can be anything.

Comment: You should consider moving from directly serving with node.js to using a reverse proxy (e.g. with nginx) that handles your subdomains etc. This can be set up very easily and has many other advantages besides taking complexity out ouf your node application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in your case by setting the 'subdomain offset' express app setting to **3**.

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('subdomain offset', 3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This certainly helped and the link provided much required information.